# DataGrid with different behavior in production environment

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, wpf-controls, production-environment

Developing an app, I setup a data binding for a Datagrid:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="IdentifyDetailsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HeadersVisibility="None" 
                      Background="White" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.(Controls:DataItem.Data),ElementName=IdentifyComboBox, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" 
              DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Keys"  Binding="{Binding Path=Key}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Values"  Binding="{Binding Path=Value}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

if I run this code in development machine, it duplicates the columns, so far, I understand that they are duplicated because I define a binding to the Items Source and to the explicit declaration of the columns:

But if I take this code to production machine it looks fine (just two columns):

the difference that I found between machines is that production has  the framework extended 4

the development machine does not have that version of framework. does any one has documentation about that behavior?

Comment: Maybe you have different datasource(connection string for example) on you production machine, with no data. Because of that AutoGenerateColumns=true doesn't generate columns. And you have only 2 defined columns.

Comment: @JackMalkovich, thanks for your comment, but I do not connect the data grid to a DB, the datasource is a logical object (dictionary) that only has keys and values (2 columns)...I do not have enough  reputation to post the images :(